# UX/UI implications of user working under stress/time pressure

Tags: user-centered-design, health

In UCD, it is often mentioned that the context of usage of the app is very important for designer to keep in mind. I am designing a decision support system application for field healthcare workers that don't have a lot of time for every session, and on the hand need to be precise with what they mark on the app. Of course, I understand that in terms of usability, that means I need to set efficiency goals and benchmarks and verify them through usability tests. I wonder, though, what are additional measures I should consider when designing the UI/UX. This is what I came up with so far:

- Clear spatial orientation of the app - every element has its place, consistent through the screens.
- Big fonts; big clickable areas for radio buttons/checkboxes;
- Clear emphasis on the important things (symptoms/warnings)

Anything else that I'm missing here?

Comment: Immediate feedback (audible, visual) to the operator that an action took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also place high importance on some additional areas

1) Performance - Set a performance budget for the development team, mark specific animations/visual flair that can be cut to meet this performance budget, have money earmarked for additional system infrastructure and dynamic scaling plans.

2) Accessibility - What good are the UI elements if they are invisible to the user or inaccessible to certain input devices?

3) Immediate User Feedback - as @Lior specified above.

I highly recommend watching the talk by Eric Meyer [Designing for Crisis](https://vimeo.com/148927676)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know if this is within your app's scope, but I did something that while not entirely your user case, has some relation because users are people with tremors (*Parkinson, Huntington, Alzheimer*). Hitting a target is very difficult and frustrating for them, so I recommended (and it was implemented) **aural support**, which proved to be quite effective since now users can use the app with just voice commands. I think something like this could help in your case.

## Some additional reading on the subject:

- [Semi-aural Interfaces: Investigating Voice-controlled Aural Flows](https://academic.oup.com/iwc/article-abstract/28/6/826/2417086/Semi-aural-Interfaces-Investigating-Voice)
- [The Future of Aural Interfaces is Clear in 2017](https://www.letsnurture.com/blog/future-aural-interfaces-clear-2017.html)
- [EYES-FREE INTERACTION WITH AURAL USER INTERFACES](https://scholarworks.iupui.edu/bitstream/handle/1805/8036/RohaniGhahari_iupui_0104D_10053.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Answer (score 1):

A couple other things to consider.

Because your users are likely to be interrupted, I'd also auto-save their entries so they don't lose everything if they don't get the chance to finish and hit the Save button.

If they're using different machines through the day, save their state and open to the last page they were on when they sign in, including on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

Being tired and stressed is remarkably similar to being drunk. So you could [pay someone to get drunk and try to use your app](http://theuserisdrunk.com/).

There's a guy who actually makes a living doing this, and he has compiled a [list of recommendations for websites](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/78184134-10-things-i-learned-about-ux-by-being-drunk); several of his guidelines apply to apps as well.

1. Don't present users with a wall of text
2. Tell users what the app is for / have a clear purpose for each page
3. Solve a need (have a clear user story for each feature)
4. Don't repeat yourself
5. Hide anything non-essential (progressive disclosure)

to which I would add:

6. **Have a clear workflow.** If your app is designed to perform specific tasks frequently (e.g. record a diagnosis), then it needs to be nice and simple to do the task and save the data recorded.

And I totally agree that **immediate user feedback** is necessary, and **auto-saving of input** in case they get interrupted.